# ionic: label input label input in one line

Tags: ionic-framework

Using Ionic, I want to put one label with an input and then another label with an input right after them, all in the same line.

I did the following

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label>I bought</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" min=0.1 value=1></ion-input>
      <ion-label>items for $</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" min=0.1 value=0.1></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

For some reason, I have the 2 labels together and only then the 2 inputs together. In the same line though.
How come the order got mixed up and how can I make them in the correct order?

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste this. This will work.

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-label>I bought</ion-label>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-input type="number" min=0.1 value=1></ion-input>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-label>items for $</ion-label>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-input type="number" min=0.1 value=0.1></ion-input>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this already. The problem is the spacing between the items. I want them to be near one another so it will look like one sentence. Adding no-margins (to the inputs) and no-padding (to the cols) made them closer together but the inputs were placed higher in the line and the labels lower in the line. Also, I wonder if using col/row is the real/clean solution to my question. Maybe I just miss a small thing to make my example work.